# How do I plot JUST the mean and stdev of data in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I cannot for the life of me find a similar question to this, and I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to do this. It seems like it should be a simple thing!

**The setup:** I have some X vs Y data grouped into bins, and each bin contains X and Y data points. For each bin, I would like to plot the mean of X vs mean of Y along with their respective stdevs, and most importantly: color code each bin using the Seaborn "colorblind" palette (this is mandatory).

**What I've tried:** Everything under the sun. Lineplot, scatterplot, catplot, plotpoints. And when none of those were working, I tried to use matplotlib's "errorbars" but I apparently can't seem to export Seaborn's "colorblind" palette to matplotlib so that was a bust too.

**Some dummy code:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

some_data = pd.DataFrame({'X':[9,10,11,12,39,40,41,42], 'Y':[99,100,110,111,499,500,510,511], 'Bin':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]})
```

**Results of some tries:**

```
sns.pointplot(x="X", y="Y", data=some_data, legend='full', hue='Bin')
```

[image: pointplot]
Scatterplot completely screws up the x-axis scale, so that's another issue that I haven't been able to work around.

```
sns.lineplot(x="X", y="Y", data=some_data, legend='full', hue='Bin', err_style="band", estimator="mean", ci='sd')
```

[image: lineplot]
Better but it's just drawing a line between the points instead of calculating the mean and stdev, which, I thought it would do when I specify an estimator and confidence interval method!!!!!.

```
sns.scatterplot(x="X", y="Y", data=some_data, legend='full', hue='Bin')
```

Scatterplot is fine, but it doesn't possess *estimator* functionality so I'm literally just plotting the raw data.

[image: scatterplot]

I'm just completely lost on what to do. I've been at this all night. It's 4:30 AM and I've barely slept for the past few nights. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would the desired result be 2 scatter points (mean of x and y for each bin), with an errorbar for the stdev?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this -- yes, the desired output is one mean and stdev for each bin of 4 data points, so 2 points total, with error bars [or something akin] over each point to represent the stdevs

Answer (score 4):

The following approach draws an ellipse using the mean and sdevs:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[9,10,11,12,39,40,41,42], 'Y':[99,100,110,111,499,500,510,511], 'Bin':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]})
means = df.groupby('Bin').mean()
sdevs = df.groupby('Bin').std()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = ['crimson', 'dodgerblue']
sns.scatterplot(x='X', y='Y', hue='Bin', palette=colors, data=df, ax=ax)
sns.scatterplot(x='X', y='Y', data=means, color='limegreen', label='means', ax=ax)

for (_, mean), (_, sdev), color in zip(means.iterrows(), sdevs.iterrows(), colors):
    ellipse = Ellipse((mean['X'], mean['Y']), width=2*sdev['X'], height=2*sdev['Y'],
                          facecolor=color, alpha=0.3)
    ax.add_patch(ellipse)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Here is a more elaborate example, showing ellipses for 1, 2 and 3 times the sdev.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

K = 5
N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.normal(np.tile(np.random.uniform(10, 40, K), N), np.tile([3, 4, 7, 9, 10], N)),
                   'Y': np.random.normal(np.tile(np.random.uniform(90, 500, K), N), np.tile([20, 25, 8, 22, 18], N)),
                   'Bin': np.tile(np.arange(1, K + 1), N)})
means = df.groupby('Bin').mean()
sdevs = df.groupby('Bin').std()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
colors = ['crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'limegreen', 'turquoise', 'gold']
for ax in axes:
    sns.scatterplot(x='X', y='Y', hue='Bin', palette=colors, s=5, ec='none', data=df, ax=ax)
    sns.scatterplot(x='X', y='Y', marker='o', s=50, fc='none', ec='black', label='means', data=means, ax=ax)
    if ax == axes[1]:
        for (_, mean), (_, sdev), color in zip(means.iterrows(), sdevs.iterrows(), colors):
            for sdev_mult in [1, 2, 3]:
                ellipse = Ellipse((mean['X'], mean['Y']), width=2 * sdev['X'] * sdev_mult,
                                  height=2 * sdev['Y'] * sdev_mult,
                                  facecolor=color, alpha=0.2 if sdev_mult == 1 else 0.1)
                ax.add_patch(ellipse)
plt.show()
```

[image: multiples of sdev]

Answer (score 1):

I acknowledge this is not the **full** answer - but I hope it will help with the **data stats** and give you some direction with the plot.  I'm not terribly good with matplot/seaborn, so to get this over to you, I've quickly written the graph in plotly.  I hope it at least provides some direction for you ...

#### Mean / Std:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import iplot

x = [9, 10, 11, 12, 39, 40, 41, 42]
y = [99, 100, 110, 111, 499, 500, 510, 511]
b = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'bin': b})
df = df.groupby(['bin']).agg(['mean', 'std'])
df.columns = ['_'.join(c).rstrip('_') for c in df.columns.to_list()]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

#### Output:

```
    bin x_mean  x_std       y_mean  y_std
0   1   10.5    1.290994    105     6.377042
1   2   40.5    1.290994    505     6.377042
```

#### Plotting:

```
data = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    data.append({'x': [row.x_mean],
                 'y': [row.y_mean],
                 'mode': 'markers',
                 'name': '{} mean'.format(row.bin),
                 'marker': {'size': 25}})
    data.append({'x': [row.x_std],
                 'y': [row.y_std],
                 'mode': 'markers',
                 'name': '{} std'.format(row.bin),
                 'marker': {'size': 25}})
iplot({'data': data})
```

#### Output:

Note that as the stds are the same, the red/purple dots overlay each other.

[image]

I hope this helps a bit ...